# How to get images from .net core web api wwwroot folder from angular using path which saved in database

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an ecommerce website using Angular 7 and .net core webAPI 3.1. **Both angular and webapi are created separately**. i have saved product details(i.e there name ,price,image path etc) in database and images are saved to wwwroot\Products folder in .net project. Path of images is saved in db with product details.
On angular side I want to show product list with there details and images.Now i am facing a problem how can i get list of product with there images in angular. I can get all details of products (i.e product list) with images file path, but images is not accessable because path is of server side wwwroot\Products folder which cannot be accessed from angular.
So how can i get images with product

My Model to get Images Detail is as follow:

```
public class ProductImagesVM
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPerc { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Material { get; set; }       
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string ColorId { get; set; }
    public string SizeId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int TotalAmount { get; set; }

}
```

This is my Controller method to retrieve List of Products

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult GetProductImagesVM()
    {
        return Ok(this.db.ProductImagesVM.ToList());
    }
```

My sample response is

```
[
{
    "productId": "9e9253dc-219c-43fd-8725-2b43c415afd7",
    "name": "Product 1",
    "code": "11",
    "price": 500,
    "discount": 300,
    "discountPerc": 60,
    "categoryId": "61a4d55c-6c42-4ad4-a467-382840122a25",
    "material": "khadar",
    "description": "description",
    "status": 1,
    "imageId": "99588638-025a-4d21-a591-56ec06e3bcd3",
    "path": "Products\\24a9bedf-9d82-4683-902a-e160a87e25b9.jpg",
    "colorId": "",
    "sizeId": "",
    "quantity": 0,
    "totalAmount": 0
},
{
    "productId": "4ae044d6-f177-404f-91f9-c0feab678310",
    "name": "Men Shoes",
    "code": "11",
    "price": 999,
    "discount": 70,
    "discountPerc": 7,
    "categoryId": "009e546f-2fe5-4ab2-b205-7ae562d82a32",
    "material": "khadar",
    "description": "description",
    "status": 1,
    "imageId": "012f0f16-4c5e-4234-a483-861f5feff0da",
    "path": "Products\\d67d98b4-cd38-489d-bd2b-512729e94317.jpg",
    "colorId": "",
    "sizeId": "",
    "quantity": 0,
    "totalAmount": 0
}
```

]

This is how i save image to wwwroot/Products on server side

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("[action]")]
    public IActionResult AddProducts()
    {
        try
        {

            var files = Request.Form.Files;
            if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
            {
                var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(Request.Form["product"]);
                var images = new List<Images>();
                var productSizeLink = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductSizeLink>>(Request.Form["size"]);
                var productColorLink = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductColorLink>>(Request.Form["colors"]);
                // var category = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Category>(Request.Form["category"]);
                // var indexImg=Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["imgIndex"]);


                this.db.Product.Add(product);
                foreach (var item in productSizeLink)
                {
                    this.db.ProductSizeLink.Add(item);
                }
                foreach (var item in productColorLink)
                {
                    this.db.ProductColorLink.Add(item);
                }

                string webRootPath = this._env.WebRootPath;
                var folderName = "Products";
                string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
                }
                var pathtodb = "";
                var i = 1;
                foreach (var item in files)
                {
                    if (item.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string fileName = item.FileName;
                        var gid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, gid + Path.GetExtension(fileName));
                        pathtodb = Path.Combine(folderName, gid + Path.GetExtension(fileName));
                        images.Add(new Images { ImageId = Guid.NewGuid(), ProductId = product.ProductId, Path = pathtodb, OrderBy = i++ });
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                        {
                            item.CopyTo(stream);
                        }
                    }

                }
                foreach (var item2 in images)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item2.ImageId + " <<----------------------------");
                    this.db.Images.Add(item2);

                }

                this.db.SaveChanges();

                return Ok("Product Added Successfully");

            }

            return Ok("No files found");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }


        // return Ok("Done");
    }
```

Comment: The easiest would be alter the backend to have a REST endpoint `/products/` that delivers exactly that.

Comment: @unsignedmind can you please elaborate i didnt get your point

Comment: Well angular is a client side framework and cannot access directories on your server. Therefor your backend needs to provide a Endpoint to which the angular application can make a HTTP request.

Comment: How can i achieve that. where should i make changes. Actually i am new to this therefore i am unable to understand. do i have to make changes in controller @unsignedmind

Comment: I am not familiar with asp.net. I do my backends in nodejs and my product data is usually stored in a data base not in direcotries. I assume that you know how to get your products into the controller. By that I mean accessible as a variable. In the controller you need the products and the image urls. Map them together so that every product conists also of the image url. This object must then be returned.

Comment: Your `path` should be something like this: `"path": "http://YourWebApiCore30/Products/24a9bedf-9d82-4683-902a-e160a87e25b9.jpg"` where `YourWebApiCore30` is the name of your application. I don't know how exactly you have this setup, but Products in wwwroot should be browsable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use img like this(xxx is the port of webapi):

```
<img src="https://localhost:xxx/images/red.PNG">
```

Here is a demo(I have cors in startup):

[image]

Startup.cs(add `app.UseStaticFiles();` as below，so that you can get img with url):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            //add it here
            app.UseStaticFiles();


            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Angular:
[image]

Comment: the path in my case is `http://localhost:5000/Products/a6a4e701-e701-4b65-b0a6-de81e2e37602.jpg` when i hit this path in browser it shows the image but when i put this url as src in <img> it says could not load image and in console i am getting following error:
`GET http://localhost:5005/localhost:5000/Products/a6a4e701-e701-4b65-b0a6-de81e2e37602.jpg 404 (Not Found)`
and this is my HTML `<img src="http:\localhost:5000\Products\a6a4e701-e701-4b65-b0a6-de81e2e37602.jpg">` @Yiyi You

Comment: Remmember that my angular app is running on `localhost:5005` and webapi is running on `localhost:5000` @Yiyi

Comment: Do you add `src="http://localhost:5000/Products/a6a4e701-e701-4b65-b0a6-de81e2e37602.jpg"`?you need to add the full path and don't add `/` before it.Yes,you need to use localhost:5000

Comment: Ok the problem was with the `/` i was using `\\` thanks alot :)

Comment: Perfect! in my case the problem was with the Port! i was using Angular Port whereas i was supposed to use the port at which my API is running, makes sense.